# How to Adjust Estimator to Make Unbiased?

Tags: statistics, expectation, parameter-estimation

[image]

Attached is my working.

As I've labelled, I'm not sure how to get to the answer from my expected value notation. Can somebody help?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the original question, it is statement that

$$\mathbb{E}[\hat{\theta}]=\theta + \frac1n$$

Hence we have

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\hat{\theta}- \frac1n\right]=\theta $$

I think your msitake is misread the question $\theta + \frac1n$ as $\frac{\theta+1}{n}$.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks! But when I do the same thing with the same logic, i.e. multiply by K and solve, I get K = θn - Kθn =/= to the answer, right?

Comment: we can't always multiply things to correct things right? sometimes we do subtraction, or multiple operations. the question is like how would you solve for $\theta$.

Comment: So is an appropriate way to solve this type of thing just to have θ + 1/n = theta hat and then solve for θ?

Comment: Ultimately your goal is to prove expectation of some estimator is equal to $\theta$.  Note that every operation that I work with so far  obey linerity.

Comment: Right, but since this expected value has θ in it, then setting that expectation = theta hat and solving for θ is still the way to achieve the answer isn't it? Or is that wrong? I.e. θ + 1/n = theta hat is the same as θ = theta hat - 1/n, which is the correct adjusted estimator. The reason being that θ is the population parameter.

Comment: try to keep the expectation when you solve things.